# How to change the sample word count to return the labels?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below code performs a word count of collection type : `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, Int)])]`

```
val words : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, Int)])] = sc.parallelize( List(("a" , List( ("test" , 1) , ("test" , 1)))) )
val missingLabels : RDD[(String, Int)] = words.flatMap(m => m._2).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
println("Labels Missing")
missingLabels.collect().foreach(println)
```

How can I grab the labels also so that instead of `("test" , 2)` the value `("a" , ("test" , 2))` is extracted ? In other words type `RDD[ (String , List( (String, Int) ))]`.

Comment: What if the same word appears with two different labels? Should those be summed? Under which label? Are the keys in `words` unique?

Comment: @DanielDarabos if the same word appears under different labels then the word is summed individually for each label. Yes the keys in words are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key can be repeated, then I am assuming you want to reduce it all down to one pairing? If so:

```
def reduceList(list: List[(String, Int)]) = list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.aggregate(0)(_ + _._2, _ + _))

val words : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, Int)])] = sc.parallelize( List(("a" , List( ("test" , 1) , ("test" , 1)))) )
val mergedList = words.mapValues((list : List[(String, Int)]) => reduceList(list).toList)
val missingLabels = mergedList.reduceByKey((accum: List[(String, Int)], value: List[(String, Int)]) =>
  {
    val valueMap = value.toMap
    val accumMap = accum.toMap
    val mergedMap = accumMap ++ valueMap.map{case(k,v) => k -> (v + accumMap.getOrElse(k, 0))}
    mergedMap.toList
  })
  missingLabels.foreach(println)
```

Comment: what version of Spark are you running ? I receive compiler error Multiple markers at this line:
◾value mapValues is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, Int)])]

 for Line : val mergedList = words.mapValues((list: List[(String, Int)]) => reduceList(list).toList)

Comment: I forgot to import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, you should just play with tuples a little bit.

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
val words : RDD[(String, List[(String, Int)])] = sc.parallelize( List(("a" , List( ("test" , 1) , ("test" , 1)))) )
val wordsWithLabels = words
  .flatMap { 
      case (label, listOfValues) => listOfValues.map {
        case (word,count) => (word, (label, count))
      }
  }
val result = wordsWithLabels
  .reduceByKey {
    case ((label1, count1), (label2, count2)) => 
      (label1, count1 + count2)
   }
  .map {
    case (word, (label, count)) =>
      (label, (word, count))
  }
result.foreach(println)
```

Comment: flatMap will lose any hash partitioning that might already be available.